# How to calculate NPV

Tags: php

i want to calculate the NPV ( Net Present Value ) using PHP.

Below is the detail which i have.

```
    discount rate : 15%

    Cash Flow Values per Year:

    Year 1: 110000
    Year 2: 122000 
    Year 3: 135200
    Year 4: 149720
    Year 5: 157706
    Year 6: 166091
```

NPV Formula which i am using.

```
NPV = sum of all years( (Ci)/(1+r)^i)

i=1,2,3,4,5,...
Ci= Cash Flow for year i
r=rate of discount
```

Any help.

Thanks In advance

Avinash

Comment: Show us the code you've written and explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it seems a simple calculation. Do stuff like $result = $a + $b / $c, etc. Can you be more specific? What have you tried to do so far and specifically what problem did you run into? Also do note that if you are asking about the NPV formula (and not how to do calculations in php) you are off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would calculate the NPV of each year using the following formula:
(value) / ((1 + 0.15) ^ (year)) then sum all the results to get your final NPV - where ^ means to the power of.

So for year two it would be: 122000 / ((1.15)^ 2).

At the current point in time the power ^ value would be 0

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include the code - seems like there is an issue in the algorithm - what value do you calculate for the year 1 entry? - It is also possible that some rounding issue might be occuring in the calculation

Comment: i have not created any code for this yet, i am just testing it on paper for now.
I am taking 0 as a first year value. will it be a problem?

Comment: 0 means the current point in time - not a year from now, so $1 received now would be worth $1 at this point in time, there is no change in what that $1 would be worth if received now

Comment: i am not getting that what are u trying to say,
Can you please become some more descriptive??

Comment: Sorry by 0 do you mean the value used as the power or do you mean the amount received at that point in time (the numerator in equation)? - the previous comment assumed you were talking about the power of value

Comment: Can you post the equation you are using (even if on paper) - will be easier to detect what is going wrong with your result then

Comment: Sorry for late reply, been away.
So was your final formula this?:

=(110000/(1.15)^1) + (122000/(1.15)^2) + (135200/(1.15)^3) + (149720/(1.15)^4) + (157706/(1.15)^5) + (166091/(1.15)^6)

You can pop this equation into excel (or some expression evaluator) to see what the result should be

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from the work done by TommySzalapski here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26875482/Finding-NPV-net-present-value-with-PHP.html

The best way to do it is to first create an array of your cash flows. Remember that arrays start at 0, so if there is no cash flow at year 0 then [0] = 0. If there is a cash out lay make this negative.

```
$cf = array(0, 110000, 122000, 135200, 149720, 157706, 166091 );
```

Then create variables for your inputs:

```
$years = 6;
$discountRate = 0.15;
```

Then you can use TommySzalapski formula

```
function npv($rate, $values, $year) {
    for ($i=$year;$i>=0;$i-=1) {
        $npv = ($values[$i] + $npv) / (1 + $rate);
    }
    return '$'.number_format($npv,2,'.',' ');
}
```

so plugin:

```
$NPV = npv($discountRate, $cf, 6); // You can also use the $years variable here

echo $NPV;
```

Answer is $445 751.54 which is the same as the NPV formula gives in Excel.